# Website for different mobile device dimensions

Tags: mobile, size, dimensions, smartphone

Recently I read a blog post that pointed out to a well crafted website for consulting different mobile device dimensions (especially iPhones and iPads) with wireframes and all. You could probably also print them for quick reference.

There are a few that I am already aware of, such as [mobiledevicesize.com](http://mobiledevicesize.com) and [phone-size.com](http://phone-size.com), but this one was somehow different: very minimalistic with a good taste of design in general.

Unfortunately I cannot remember neither which blog was it in nor the referenced website, so could you please share what other websites of this kind do you know?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, came across it in a presentation. Was it this one? http://www.mydevice.io/devices/

Comment: Not really, although this one is pretty–ish too. Thanks!